# Did the session id value disappear from the workbench?

Tags: session, workbench

I remember that the session information menu option used to display a *session id* value in the workbench? Is that no longer visible?

I can still get this by executing this line of code in the Apex Execute box.

```
System.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Comment: It appears so... It's not showing for me either under Session Information.

Thanks for the UserInfo.getSessionId() solution though.

Comment: yep looks like it's gone, but thanks for the apex execute solution :)

Answer (score 2):

After summer'17, it's gone from Debug logs as well.
**System.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId())** prints **SESSION_ID_REMOVED**

If you want to get session id, you can try printing this in VF page with {!GETSESSIONID()}, like

```
<apex:page>
    {!GETSESSIONID()}
</apex:page>
```

Comment: See [Session_ID_Remove Issue in API callouts in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180216/102) with regards to the Session ID being removed from the debug log and replaced with `SESSION_ID_REMOVED`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. Unfortunately it's gone..

[image]

But, thanks for alternative solution.

DeveloperConsole > OpenExecuteAnonymousWindow > [Run below code to retrieve your session ID]

```
System.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

> Note: Session is valid for 2 hours.

Comment: does not work either in developer console --> anony window get this error `SESSION_ID_REMOVED`

Comment: Yeah they removed it for security reason. Check [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179845/session-id-remove-issue-in-api-callouts-in-salesforce/180216#180216) for alternative solution