# Getting Error : "access_token": "SESSION_ID_REMOVED"

Tags: rest-api, integration, callout, access

We are doing salesforce to salesforce integration using REST API(both are developer edition),

**Problem is** : I am not getting access_token in response and it's look like

> "access_token": "SESSION_ID_REMOVED",

```
public class CallOutToNiharCsInstance {

    String clientId     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('ABCD1234','UTF-8');
    String clientSecret = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('123456','UTF-8');
    String username     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('test@gmail.com','UTF-8');
    String password     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('abc#123_Security_Token','UTF-8');

    public void callOutMethod(){
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('Response is ::::::::' + res);
        system.debug('Body Is ::::::::::::' + res.getBody());
    }

}
```

Another class

```
public void storeAccessToken(){
    system.debug('URL Is ******' + System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL());
    system.debug('URL Is ******' + System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().getHost());

    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') != null) {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&code='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code')+'&redirect_uri=https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/StoreAccessToken';
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.force.com/services/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('Response is ::::::::' + res);
        system.debug('Body Is ::::::::::::' + res.getBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: Session token is hidden now from debug logs.  It is in variable, but removed from logs. How to check that -- system.assertEquals(null, res.getBody() ); will lead to exception, which shows that there is a access token

Comment: You mean `access token` is available in response, it just hide from the debug log, right ?

Comment: yes. That appeared on Summer'17

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't see a direct Session ID in the debug logs for security reasons. See [Session_ID_Remove Issue in API callouts in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180216/102).

However, it should still be possible to use it for call outs.

If you really want to see the value in the debug logs then you can alter it slightly to it doesn't appear as a valid session id.