# Not able to see Session ID in apex debug log Salesforce

Tags: apex, community, developer-console, debugging, developer

Code -

```
String sessionID = UserInfo.getSessionId();
System.debug(sessionID);
```

Should give me Session ID, Urgent as I require it for use in SOAP UI. Is there any workaround

Comment: according to this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179845/session-id-remove-issue-in-api-callouts-in-salesforce/180216 you can no longer see session id in debug logs though we can put it in use just cant print it

Comment: @User6670  thanks a lot. Found this workaround system.debug(Userinfo.getSessionId().subString(1,Userinfo.getSessionId().length())); and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has workaround to see sessionId in Debug Logs:

```
system.debug(UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + UserInfo.getSessionId().substring(15));
```

Since first 15 characters of session id is organization id, and debug logs perfectly show parts of session id string.

Comment: After a bit research, I came to know that session id starts with 005, to identify the session id, salesforce just checks these first three digits and marks it as session id, so even if we trim the first three digits in debug of session id, it should work, and then we can add 005 later whenever you want to use it @MariiaIllarionova

Comment: Please can you look into this

Comment: Yes, sure, it;s the same that I mentioned, session Id starts with organization Id, AND organization Id always starts from **005**, so you are right, you can set it like you mentioned in comment too.

Comment: that was helpful, I got to complete my SOAP UI request successfully.

Comment: Done @brian-miller